# error FOR3852: syntax error detected between QUOTE and [1]

Tags: fortran

I have the following simple Fortran program:

```
    program quotes
       implicit none
       character*1000 quote       
       integer*4 i

       open(13,file='d:\sp500.new',status='unknown')
       close(13,status='delete')

       open(12,file='d:\sp500.dat')
       open(13,file='d:\sp500.new', status='new')


       do 100 i = 1,61113
          read(12,'(A)') quote          

          if(quote[1] .eq. 'I')write(13,'(A)')quote

100    continue

       end
```

I'm trying to read in the entire string, check to see if the first character in the string = 'I' and if true write out the entire string.  I have some other testing I have to do so I need to read the input string character by character

the error message is:

```
D:\quotes.f90(18): error FOR3852: syntax error detected between QUOTE and [1]
Error executing fl32.exe.
quotes.obj - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Please use [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: You are using [] instead of (). Searching for a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct array and substring indexing parentheses are `()`, not `[]`.

You also have to always use `:` for substrings, so `quote(1:1)` is necessary.

There are no `[]` in Fortran 90 or 95. In Fortran 2003 `[ items ]` is an array constructor. In Fortran 2018 `coarray[1]` is used for a coindex of a coarray.